# Anyone know of good knowledgebase/faq software for asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am looking for knowledgebase/faq software with a developer license that is written in c#.
I have found a couple of good options for VB but would prefer C#.

Comment: I sure would like to see an answer to this as well...

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it will meet your requirements, but you might want to take a look at [Screwturn Wiki](http://www.screwturn.eu/MainPage.ashx). It's open source and written in C#/ASP.NET.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but not quite what I am looking for. I am looking for something more on the line of these products (only written in c#): instantasp.co.uk/Products/InstantKB and xigla.com/absolutefmnet/features.htm